Why does my Popp TRV 010101 reset itself to 20°C after a few seconds?
I have 3 Popp (formerly Danfoss) Z-Wave Thermostat Radiator Valves (TRV) model 010101 (see https://popp.eu/products/wireless-thermostatic-valve/) that I’ve been using for a few years :

paired with an Aeotec Z‐Stick Gen5 USB Controller
plugged into a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
running zwave-js-ui: 9.6.2.6e369a1 + zwave-js: 12.4.1
running Domoticz 2024.7

Since September 2024, one of these TRV has stopped working properly: whatever setpoint I set, and whatever the means (through Domoticz or physically on the device itself), it resets itself back to 20°C after a few seconds.
I’ve tried :

changing the batteries
factory resetting the devices
re-pairing it with the Z-Stick
looked at Honeywell TH6110D1005 Thermostat keeps resetting itself but no reply so far

Nothing had any effect.
I’m thinking of replacing the device, but not before throwing a message in a bottle here. :-)

I’ve contacted Popp support who advised me to exclude the problematic TRV node from its Z-Wave network controller.
After I did, the TRV stopped resetting to 20°C.
I included it back, and everything seems to be fine again. :-)
